# What is index.jsp file used for?

Tags: jakarta-ee

Apologies if this is a very basic question, but what exactly is a `index.jsp` file? What other jsp files are important in a web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a JSP which is named `index`. AFAIK, by default, the welcome files of a webapp include index.jsp. Which means that if you go to the URL

```
http://som.host.com/webapp/foo/bar/
```

the index.jsp located in the `/foo/bar/` directory of the webapp will be executed.